# Use Homepage as "Shop" for Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a store I'm putting up, and the store itself is located on the homepage.

I built my own template to do this and the homepage looks great. However, it looks like I actually have to set a "shop" page. When I set a shop page, it uses WooCommerce default template which looks like garbage. If I set the homepage as the shop page, it overwrites all my code.

How do I stop WooCommerce from overwriting what I already have? And what can I change within the WooCommerce templates so the shop page reflects my homepage?

I've already tried changing archive-product.php, and it has no effect whatsoever. I can even delete that file entirely and there's no change whatsoever.

My site is http://iowstore.wpengine.com

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You should select your custom template as template from backend if you want to display that as home page.

Comment: Please read [ask] and show us the code that is overwritten and explain where that is.

Comment: I have the problem than you I have found this
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-custom-shop-page/ I'm not sure if is the intended behavior but in my case makes the "Go back to the Shop" button disappear, is not the best solution but better than having merging the 2 homepages (mine + woocommerce home) Cheers!

Comment: cant answer the question till it is opened, but go to Woocommerce>settings then Products tab and under ShopPages - change Shop Page to your homepage

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't quite get what you are trying to do here. But if you just wanna show products / categories at your homepage, (which is what usually shop page displays), what I would normally do is:

1. Set homepage as 'static front page'
2. Edit the page (use text editor instead of visual editor) using HTML codes & Woocommerce shortcodes to display products http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/ e.g. [best_selling_products per_page="12" columns="4"] or [product_categories number="12" parent="0"], etc
3. css the page if necessary.

'What about the original shop page?' Just don't put it in your navigation / sitemap...

Hope that helps.

Cheers